# unable to install Entity - Framework in visual studio 2010

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, entity-framework, visual-studio

I'm using visual studio 2010, want to install entity framework. So I'm running this command

```
Install-Package EntityFramework -Version 4.3.1
```

in Package Manager Console but it shows the Following error.

[image: Error Image]

Comment: There should be .Net 4.5 to use Entity Framework 5.0. As far as I know, VS 2010 can work only with .Net 4.0 or less.

Comment: @KirillBestemyanov There are actually two separate versions of EF5, depending on the target framework. The .dll for 4.0 is actually labeled version 4.4.2, interestingly enough.

Comment: @TiesonT. its `4.3.1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The picture shows your error. Just read it. You must open a solution first and now run the command. EF from NuGet is project based.

Comment: @Ramniwaschhimpan run the same command sans version number. NuGet will install the newest your environment/project supports.